# Adapt Axis multiRef WSDL for JAXWS

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, axis

We have a very old axis web service that we need to use with a client made with jaxws. One of the methods of this web services returns a type `apachesoap:Document`, where apachesoap schema is `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap`.

The response XML looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:consultaXMLResponse xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.imagapp.app" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <consultaXMLReturn href="#id0"/>
    </ns1:consultaXMLResponse>
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" 
        soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xsi:type="ns2:Document">
      <DatosConsultaWS>
        <Registro>2974161</Registro>
      </DatosConsultaWS>
    </multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My adapted wsdl schema looks like this (I show only the response element, the rest I don't think is relevant because works fine).

```
 <element name="consultaXMLResponse">
    <complexType>
       <sequence>
          <element name="consultaXMLReturn">
             <complexType>
                <sequence>
                   <element name="DatosConsultaWS">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Registro" type="xsd:string"/> 
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
               <attribute name="href" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
               <attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
               <anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="strict"/>
             </complexType>
          </element>
       </sequence>
    </complexType>
 </element>
```

However with this element, when I call that method, my client returns null (not even a ConsultaXMLReturn with null value inside).

I don't really know if what I'm trying to do is even posible.

Ideas? thanks.